# CodeIgniter Email without SMTP not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am using CI email module, but it's not working. I don't have SMTP credentials, so trying this code to work for me.

```
   $this->load->library('email');
    // Send Emails
    $config = Array(
        'mailtype' => 'html'
    );
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from($from);
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->subject($title);
    $this->email->message($message);
    //$this->email->send();
    if ($this->email->send()) {
        $this->email->clear();
        return true;
    } else {
        die(show_error($this->email->print_debugger()));
        //return false; 
    }
```

It's giving this error

[image]

Comment: As the message says, your server isn't configure to send emails using the configured method. Maybe it's set to send using `sendmail` without having `sendmail` installed? I would recommend using SMTP since that will make your code more portable and will make sure more people can receive your emails.

Answer (score 1):

Emails usually are sent by email servers.

If you don't specify a SMTP server, your email module is trying to send emails using built-in php [email](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

But this function does not do magic. It also need a fully functional SMTP server/agent.

By default, on Unix platforms it uses local SMTP server, specified in php.ini `sendmail_path`. On Windows, you need to specify it in [`SMTP`](https://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm) parameter.